# How do I install themes?

Tags: 10.10, themes

I am very new to Ubuntu and after spending a day or two with it, I think I really liked it. its very flexible and there is so much that you can do.

I want to install nice themes on machine. Whats the best place to get it?I found [this link](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/nice-ubuntu-themes-for-jaunty-and-intrepid-users.html), but it talks about Ubuntu Jaunty? Will this work for me on Ubuntu 10.10?
If you have any other nice suggestions for themes please share.

Comment: Remember that you ***always*** have to check if a theme comes from a trustworthy source when it doesn't come from the official Ubuntu repositories.  It *is possible* that some include malware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That tutorial is for installing themes from one specific designer. Check out the site www.gnome-look.com for all sorts of other themes. Use the GTK2 filter to find ones better suited to Ubuntu's default Desktop Environment.

Most themes come in a .tar.gz format. To install them simply open up the Appearences app. (System > Preferences > Appearance) and click the themes tab. Once there, click on install new theme and a file browser should open. Navigate to where you saved the (theme).tar.gz file and select it. Ubuntu will then install the theme for you. If the install instructions happen to be different, the author usually posts them on the theme download page.

If you're looking for some cool themes, check out [Elementary](http://danrabbit.deviantart.com/art/elementary-gtk-theme-83104033), [Victory](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Victory+%28Strikes+Again%29?content=123936), and the 
[Faenza Icon Set](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Faenza?content=128143). They are my favorites!

Comment: Hi amanthethy, thanks for the solution. I really liked Elementary, but few things on this its installation guide confuse me. **For example: ## IMPORTANT ##
Murrine and Aurora engines are required for this package.
Nautilus elementary is HIGHLY recommended. There WILL be visual glitches without it.
## IMPORTANT ##**

Comment: The EASIEST way to install Elementary would be to open up a terminal (Applications>Accessories>Terminal) and type in "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementaryart/elementarydesktop && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme && sudo apt-get upgrade" !without the quotes.

This will add a repository containing the theme and it's dependancies (MUrrine, Aurora, Elementary-Nautilus, etc.) to your repo list. Then update the list and install the theme, and then upgrade your system to the latest packages (this is important for elementary-nautilus).

Comment: worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 6):

Go to **'System --> Preferences --> Appearance'** and press **"Get more themes online"**.

[image]

Download something you like and then drop the file you downloaded to the Appearance window. The files you download are usually in the **Downloads** folder.

[image]

You can download other themes from other websites, just drop what you download to the Appearance window and in a few second you will have your new themes in Ubuntu.

Comment: Once I download a theme, I dont need to extract or install it?

Comment: No, just drop the file. For the screenshots i posted I just dropped a '.tar.gz' to the appearance window!

Answer (score 1):

Best place to download themes (imo) is http://gnome-look.org
Click on the link that says GTK2.x in the left hand column.
Find one that you like and download it
Go to System->Preferences->Appearance and click the install theme button. Browse to your theme and install. That's all there is to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Just install art manager (sudo apt-get install gnome-art) and choose from different categories of elements